# Python: Call string from another class

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Im writing a GUI with Tkinter in python 2.7 where i want a username variable to get used in another class. This is my first time doing OOP, so i'm not good at all. All help is appreciated.

Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/BF9iChrF) of the full code.

```
class LoginWindow(Frame):
    def logged(self):
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()


class MainWindow(Frame):
    def saveValues(self):
        # I WANT THE USERNAME VARIABLE HERE #
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your problem in more detail, please? What have you tried so far to get the username variable? Thanks.

Comment: Totally unrelated but your app is wide opened to SQL injections. Do not build SQL queries manually from untrusted unsanitized values, learn to properly use the db-api instead, cf http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks CKE, im sorry for the little information in the question.. ive tried making the variable inside the __init__ function to later "call"(?) the class inside the other class with loginW = LoginWindow(), and use it as loginW.username but i get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup Bruno, appreciate it! But this code should be OK to use on VPN-network right?

Answer (score 0):

You can define username and password as **global variable** outside all the classes and then use them directly in whatever class you want.

Now for your code, you can try this too:

```
class LoginWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = self.entry_username.get()
        self.password = self.entry_password.get()


class MainWindow():
    def saveValues(self):
        obj = LoginWindow()
        # Access the object's variables here
        print(obj.username, obj.password)
        return "Done..."

print(MainWindow().saveValues())
```

This will print

```
("whatever_username", "password")
Done...
```

Comment: @simonjansson: If you're using classes there is almost never a reason to use global variables.

Comment: Is it possible to make the variable from Class A global, and then use it in Class B? because this way doesnt seem to work for me ...

Comment: @simonjansson I have updated my answer as per your code. Try this out.

Comment: Thanks Harshita, now i get a better understanding on how to use variables, but unfortunately i get an error.

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "script.py", line 188, in saveValues
    obj = LoginWindow()
  File "script.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.init_window()
  File "script.py", line 28, in init_window
    self.master.title("FairIT Login")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'